# Trying to make a language switcher on wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I have a perfectly working language switcher at the moment on my blog --> oihanevalbuenaredondo.be

The thing is. I don't want the language switching links in my sidebar. The plugin that I installed only allows me to drag the widget to the sidebar. So there isn't a visible code that I can just copy and paste somewhere else. (i want it at the top of my page above the header).

I have consulted the help page of the plugin which says that I can put the code `pll_the_languages( $args );` between the brackets, I need to insert a certian code. anywhere I want to switch the language. But I have no idea how. Because that code looks like a div that you put in your css. This is what the only box where I can insert my code --> [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfQ1I.png). thats the box where I can put my code in , that's what will show up above my header. I also have another page where I can put some css, div styles,...

this is the help page where they explain it: https://polylang.pro/doc/the-language-switcher/

**Can anyone tell me the code that I can insert in the box of the image?**

Comment: It really depends on where you want to show and what theme you are using. Normally you should write a function in `functions.php` of your child theme that outputs the code and hook this function to an existing action hook exposed by either WP or your theme. Depending on the action hook, you should return the initial content plus the switcher to WordPress and it will show up. That's the principle, in short.

Comment: So I will have to change things in my theme? I can't just insert a certain code inside that box?

Comment: What you put in that box will be printed inside `<head>`. It can't be anything else but `html`. And yes, the only way is to change your theme. This should be done using a child theme, so you can leave the parent theme untouched and be able to upgrade it in the future without losing any custom mods. There are other ways, but they are even more complicated, such as create a plugin. The normal way is to use child theme. This is what child themes are for. Actually, *"child theme"* is a short name for *"theme modifications that will not be deleted when i update my theme"*.

Comment: Do you have any idea what I should put in the child theme and where? I don't know much about html :s I can do a lot of simple html and css for my blog but only easy things

Comment: Maybe I can edit the plugin code? the plugin name is polylang. When I download Polylang, i get the full ZIP with all the documents and html,... Maybe I can edit the position there? that it will show up above the header on the right, with position absolute so that it is in front of the header image?

Comment: Here's how to create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).